# How to vertically align text in a row using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to vertically align text in the middle of a row.

Below is what I have done. The vertical alignment is not working. How can I align the text vertically in the middle of the row?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row align-middle" style="min-height: 500px;">
    <div class="col-6 bg-danger align-middle">
      LEFT/MIDDLE TEXT
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 bg-primary align-middle">
      RIGHT/MIDDLE TEXT
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `align-items-center` because `row` is already `display: flex`

From the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/vertical-align/),

> Please note that vertical-align only affects inline, inline-block, inline-table, and table cell elements.
>
> ...
>
> To vertically center non-inline content (like `<div>`s and more), use our flex box utilities.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row align-items-center vh-100">
    <div class="col-6 bg-danger">
      LEFT/MIDDLE TEXT
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 bg-primary">
      RIGHT/MIDDLE TEXT
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to vertically center the *contents* of the `.col-6` and not the `.col-6` within the `.row`, use `.col-6.d-flex.flex-column.justify-content-center`. This makes the `.col-6` a flex box container. You will notice in the example below that the height of the columns are the same as in your example, if this was not your intent then [dippas' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73029100/6127393) is perfectly fine.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row" style="min-height: 500px;">
    <div class="col-6 bg-danger d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      LEFT/MIDDLE TEXT
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 bg-primary d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      RIGHT/MIDDLE TEXT
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```